# addEventlistner listens to function first or the variables?

Tags: javascript

```
var value;
addEventListener('GetPatientSearchValues', function() {
var value= 20;
FunctionName();
});

Function FunctionName();
{
   value = value + 1;
}
```

My problem is i need to recieve the value 20 and i need to pass it to FunctioName. But it directly calls the function... even an `alert(value)` does not work inside the Listener, but the alert works when i don't call another `function` inside my Listner.

Comment: Your code is not valid, due to syntax errors. Can you fix them and link us to a testcase on jsfiddle.net that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: typo one fixed one above

Comment: Don't declare value within the listener (remove 'var') so both function share the global value. Not a particularly robust strategy though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As RobG suggests you could use a global variable (leave out `var` inside the function), but It would be better to use a parameter:

```
addEventListener('GetPatientSearchValues', function() {
  var value = 20;
  value = FunctionName(value);
  // use modified value here
});

Function FunctionName(v);
{
   v = v + 1;
   return v;
}
```